# ENCOG values in output file incorrectly denormalized?

Tags: java, encog

The following was produced using the most recent version of encog-workbench (3.2.0)

I was wondering if this is a bug or if I do not grasp the purpose of the output file.

When I run the [ sunspot example ][1] in the encog workbench, without seggregation, i expect the output file to have the fitted values from the model. When i create the validation chart it presents me with the figure found in the tutorial so this seems correct.

But when i go to the sunspots_output.csv output file I get the following output:

```
ssn(t-29)   ssn(t+1)    Output:ssn(t+1)
...      first thirty values have output Null ...
-0.600472813    -0.947202522    null
-0.477541371    -1            8.349050184
-0.528762805    -0.976359338      8.334476431
-0.814814815    -0.986603625      8.314903157
-0.817178881    -0.892040977      8.292847897
...
```

All the output values are around 8 for the rest of the file.

Now when i go back to the validation chart, there is a tab data, which contains the following columns:

```
Ideal            Result
-0.477541371    -0.52449577 
-0.528762805    -0.526507195
-0.814814815    -0.535029097
-0.817178881    -0.653884012
```

If I denormalize the values in these columns, I get the following.

```
66.3    60.3414868
59.8    60.08623701
23.5    59.00480764
23.2    43.92211894
```

These seem to be correct values for the actual(if i compare them with the original data) and thus these should be the predicted values in the output column.
Is this a bug or do the values in the output(t+1) column mean something else.

I copied these values to excel and denormalized by typing in the formula for (-1,1). 
I was hoping not to have to do this every time I run an experiment.

I am going to move to code eventually. Just wanted to get some preliminary results with the workbench. Using segregation results in the same problem, btw.
If its a bug I'll report it on the encog website.

Thanks for your answers,

Florian

**UPDATE**

Hey Jef, I downloaded your zip and reproduced the problem using my workbench.

The problem only arises when i do not seggregate, which i do not want to.
There are some clear differences in the .ega file created by workbench-excecutable3.2.0
When i use your .ega file and remove the seggregate section, it works.
When i use mine it doesn't. That's why i uploaded my project [here][2]:

Maybe you can discover if something new interferes with outputting the correct values.
Hope it helps!

**Update 3:**

My actual goal is to build a forecaster of which the project can be found here:
http://wikisend.com/download/477372/Myproject.rar

I was wondering if you could tell me if I am doing something definitely wrong, because currently my output is total rubbish.

Thanks again.

Comment: Care to tell me why the downvote?

Comment: I am not familiar with filedropper.  It wants to install software onto my system prior to download?  Is there any way to bypass that step and just download your file?

Comment: If i go to the link, I just have to enter a captcha and it downloads...

Here is a different link...
http://wikisend.com/download/827766/sunspots.rar

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error, but when I ran my own sunspots prediction I did get predicted values closer to the expected range.  You might try running the zipped version of the example, found here.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/dload/encog/example/workbench/SunspotExample.zip

You should be able to run the EGA file and it will produce an output file.  Some of my data are as follows:

```
"year" "mon" "ssn" "dev" "Output:ssn(t+1)"
1948 5 174.0 69.3 156.3030108771
1948 6 167.8 26.6 168.4791037592
1948 7 142.2 28.3 208.1090604116
1948 8 157.9 35.3 186.0234029962
1948 9 143.3 55.9 131.5008296846
1948 10 136.3 44.9 93.0720770479
1948 11 95.8 21.8 89.8269594386
```

Perhaps comparing the EGA file for the above zip to your EGA file.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I added an update to my post.

But i think im just mistaken in my use of the output file, its only updated when seggregation is used right?

Is their a way to extract the values seen in the validation chart, but denormalized?

Comment: Okay, I did some debugging with this.  The problem seems to be that when you drop the validation step, the wizard sets the evaluation file to the normalized file.  evalFile=FILE_NORMALIZE  This causes a double-normalization.  It should be evalFile=FILE_RAW. However, it seems that causes an array bounding error with the eval.  Bottom line, there seems to be a bug or two with the way that time-series works when you do not create an evaluation set.  I will need to evaluate that further and fix in the next release.